# How to keep Excel pivot table from sorting?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a sheet in which Column B shows the name of products. They could be entered in random order.

```
_Generation_  _Product_  _Quantity_
 Existing     Hard Drive     1
 Proposed     SS Drive       1

 Existing     Blank DVDs    10
 Proposed     Flash Drive    3

 Existing     Lg. Notepads  10
 Proposed     Sm. Notepads  50
```

My pivot table extracts the "Proposed" rows. The leftmost column draws from that Column B.

```
_Product_     _Quantity_
 Flash Drive     3
 Sm. Notepads    50
 SS Drive        1
```

It seems to list the products in alphabetical order.  I assumed that my client would prefer that, but he'd actually like them to be in the same order as on the sheet they refer to.

Is that actually possible? If not, is there an alternative to pivot table in this case? I'm open to a VBA solution.

(A product may occasionally appear in Column B multiple times. I know that they will appear in successive rows on the pivot table. I hope my client can live with that.)

Comment: Can you show an example of your data and pivot table using mock data? More detail can make it easier to provide better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PivotTable has 4 areas: Report Filter, Column Labels, Row Labels and Values.

From your mock table, I assume that your *Product* is in Row Labels and *Quantity* in Values. Items in Row Labels can be manually adjust but click and drag. The cursor will change into the movable icon. The table stays in the same order unless you auto-fill it.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I can ask my client to manually re-order the rows each time he fills out one of these sheets!